# Social authentication for Google failing with Vue.js and django-rest-auth

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am following a blog that shows us how we can use vue-authenticate with django restframework for social authentication.

This is the blog: https://medium.com/@dobrotek6/drfsamv-django-rest-framework-social-auth-mongo-vuejs-part-1-c5c907dd7b69

However, the blog uses some the social-auth framework which I am not using. I'm using the django-rest-auth package.

I tried to set it up accordingly but I am running into some issues.

```
redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080/',
url: 'http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/google/',
```

The above code shows the links I'm placing in the provider settings according to the vue-authenticate documentation

```
this.$auth.authenticate('google', {provider: "google- 
oauth2"}).then(function (response)
```

The above code shows the authentication method according to the documentation in vue-authenticate that I copied from the blog. This is where I get the error that says authentication failed.

What exactly is it that I'm doing wrong? I can't seem to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem, the solution is quite easy but hard to found.

You need to add a tokenPath field to the configuration of the Vue-authenticate to allow vue to locate the token in the response.

In my case Django returns the token in 'token' field, but it may be different in your case.

Example code:

```
Vue.use(VueAuthenticate, {
  baseUrl: 'youApiDomain',
  storageType: 'localStorage',
  tokenPath: 'token',

  providers: {
    google: {
      clientId: 'yourClientId',
      redirectUri: '',
      url: 'authenticationUrl',
    }
  }
});
```

Solution found on: https://github.com/dgrubelic/vue-authenticate/issues/157#issuecomment-487063363